# mysql select multi rows equal from row 2

Tags: mysql, select, union-all

I have two tables:

```
TableA          TableB
ID_A            ID_B
P1              Text
P2
P3
P4
```

-

```
TableB
ID_B    Text
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
5       E
6       F
7       G
```

-

```
TableA
ID_A    P1  P2  P3  P4
1       7   5   6   6
```

thanks to Nick who helped me
[USER Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick)

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM (SELECT ID_A, P1 AS P FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_A, P2 FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_A, P3 FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_A, P4 FROM TableA) p
JOIN TableA a ON a.ID_A = p.ID_A
JOIN TableB b ON b.ID_B = p.P
ORDER BY a.ID_A, b.ID_B
```

I get:

```
ID_A    P1  P2  P3  P4    ID_B Text
1       7   5   6   6      5    E
1       7   5   6   6      6    F
1       7   5   6   6      6    F
1       7   5   6   6      7    G
```

How can I get this?

```
ID_A    P1  P2  P3  P4    ID_B Text
1       7   5   6   6      7    G
1       7   5   6   6      5    E
1       7   5   6   6      6    F
1       7   5   6   6      6    F
```

1°  row   P1 = ID_B

2°  row   P2 = ID_B

3°  row   P3 = ID_B

4°  row   P4 = ID_B

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRpqNiUmpRVJJ4gMP66Ywn/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because there is no order in the derived table of `P` values. To make it possible to order that, we can add another field which represents the `P` number (as in `P1`, `P2` etc.) and order by that instead of `ID_B`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM (SELECT 1 AS PNUM, ID_A, P1 AS P FROM TableA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, ID_A, P2 FROM TableA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, ID_A, P3 FROM TableA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4, ID_A, P4 FROM TableA) p
JOIN TableA a ON a.ID_A = p.ID_A
JOIN TableB b ON b.ID_B = p.P
ORDER BY a.ID_A, p.PNUM
```

Output:

```
ID_A    P1  P2  P3  P4  ID_B    Text
1       7   5   6   6   7       G
1       7   5   6   6   5       E
1       7   5   6   6   6       F
1       7   5   6   6   6       F
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRpqNiUmpRVJJ4gMP66Ywn/8)

Comment: thanks 1000 Nick
You are a genius of the sql language.
My knowledge of sql is basic.
Thanks to everyone who contributed, but the best solution is Nick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`, `WHEN` for a custom sort order. This will show the result in the desired sorting

```
 SELECT a.*, b.*
 FROM (SELECT ID_A, P1 AS P FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_A, P2 FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_A, P3 FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_A, P4 FROM TableA) p
 JOIN TableA a ON a.ID_A = p.ID_A
 JOIN TableB b ON b.ID_B = p.P
 ORDER BY CASE b.ID_B
     WHEN 7 THEN 4
     WHEN 5 THEN 3
     ELSE 2
 END DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TableA as a1
left join TableB as b1 on ID_B = p1
union ALL
SELECT * FROM TableA
left join TableB on ID_B = p2
union ALL
SELECT * FROM TableA
left join TableB on ID_B = P3
union ALL
SELECT * FROM TableA
left join TableB on ID_B = p4
```